# Is iterating with for..of loop over iterator instead of iterable is legal?

Tags: javascript, iterator, iterable, for-of-loop

The recommended way of iterating over an iterable object is with for..of loop over the object itself like this:

```
const a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ];
for(const item of a)
  console.log(item);
```

I have been experimenting with iterating and found out that the following also works with exactly the same result:

```
const a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ];
let iter = a[Symbol.iterator]();
for(const item of iter)
  console.log(item);
```

And even this works:

```
const a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ];
let iter = a[Symbol.iterator]();
let iter2 = iter[Symbol.iterator]();
for(const item of iter2)
  console.log(item);
```

Regarding for..of loop, I did not see recommendations to iterate over iterator instead of iterable. See, for example, [for..of in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Is it legal to iterate this way?

Comment: You will notice that `iter === iter2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for..of` assumes an Iterable (something that has `Symbol.iterator`) see https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forinofheadevaluation, point 7.

When you pass a built-in Iterator, like `StringIterator` or `ArrayIterator`, it's no problem, because for butil-in Iterators (which inherit from `IteratorPrototype`) `Symbol.iterator` just returns itself (https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-%iteratorprototype%-@@iterator).

User-defined iterators are not guaranteed to obey this rule, but it's a good practice to design them like this.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Is it guaranteed for each and every iterable object, at least built-in one? Because I can implement my custom iterable without this rule obeyed. And other developers also can. Seems like it may or may not work in all cases.